# Is it true that $p^2 + 2 \sqrt{3}r \cdot p \geq 20Rr + 5r^2$ for an acute triangle with semiperimeter $p$, inradius $r$, and circumradius $R$?

Tags: geometry, inequality

I was wondering if the following inequality is true (and if so, why):
$$p^2 + 2 \sqrt{3}r \cdot  p \geq 20Rr + 5r^2$$
for an ***acute triangle*** with semiperimeter $p$, radius of incircle $r$, and circumradius $R$.

***My approach:***

I tried to prove this with Gerretsen $p^2 \geq 16Rr - 5r^2$ iff $ \sqrt{3} p\geq 2R + 5r$ which is clearly false.

Then, maybe apply Euler inequality $R \geq 2r$, by proving that $p^2 + 2\sqrt{3} rp \geq 20Rr + 2Rr + r^2$ iff $p \geq (R+r) \sqrt{3}$ which doesn't look true at all (a weird Mitrinovic-like inequality).

And I'm stuck since all approaches that tackle directly the RHS will at some point diverge to $R \leq2r$ which is clearly false. Is that because I am taking the *"wrong road"* or simply because the inequality is false?
Any help is appreciated.

***P.S.*** I want to use the fact that I am considering an acute triangle, but I do not know **how.**

Answer (score 1):

In the standard notation we need to prove that
$$\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{4}+2\sqrt3\cdot\frac{2S}{a+b+c}\cdot\frac{a+b+c}{2}\geq20\cdot\frac{abc}{4S}\cdot\frac{2S}{a+b+c}+5\cdot\frac{4S^2}{(a+b+c)^2}$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^2+8\sqrt3S\geq\frac{40abc}{a+b+c}+\frac{80S^2}{(a+b+c)^2}.$$
If we'll prove that $$4\sqrt3S\geq\sum_{cyc}(4ab-3a^2),$$ so it's enough to prove that
$$(a+b+c)^2+\sum_{cyc}(8ab-6a^2)\geq\frac{40abc}{a+b+c}+\frac{5\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(-a^3+a^2b+a^2c-\frac{2}{3}abc\right)}{a+b+c}$$ or
$$(a+b+c)^3+\sum_{cyc}a\sum_{cyc}(8ab-6a^2)\geq40abc+5\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(-a^3+a^2b+a^2c-\frac{2}{3}abc\right),$$ which is identity!

Now, let $a^2+b^2-c^2=z,$ $a^2+c^2-b^2=y$ and $b^2+c^2-a^2=x$.

Thus, $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$, $a=\sqrt{\frac{y+z}{2}},$ $b=\sqrt{\frac{x+z}{2}}$,$c=\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-3x\right)$$ or
$$\sqrt{3}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{x^2+1}-3x\right),$$ where $xy+xz+yz=1$.

Now, let $x=\tan\frac{\alpha}{2},$ $y=\tan\frac{\beta}{2}$ and $z=\tan\frac{\gamma}{2}.$

Thus, $\alpha+\beta+\gamma=\pi$ and we need to prove that $\sum\limits_{cyc}f(\alpha)\geq0,$ where
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt3}+3\tan\frac{t}{2}-\frac{2}{\cos\frac{t}{2}}.$$
But $$f''(t)=\frac{-\sin^2\frac{t}{2}+3\sin\frac{t}{2}-1}{2\sin^3\frac{t}{2}}=\frac{\left(\frac{3+\sqrt5}{2}-\sin\frac{t}{2}\right)\left(\sin\frac{t}{2}-\frac{3-\sqrt5}{2}\right)}{2\sin^3\frac{t}{2}},$$
which says $f$ is a convex function on $\left[\frac{\pi}{3},\pi\right).$

Thus, by the Vasc's RCF Theorem(V.Cirtoaje, Algebraic inequalities(old and new methods), GIL, 2006, p.143) it's enough to prove
$$\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-3x\right)$$ for equality case of two variables.

Let $y=z=1$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{3(2x+1)}\geq2(x+1)+4\sqrt{2(x+1)}-3x-6$$ or
$$x+4+\sqrt{3(2x+1)}\geq4\sqrt{2(x+1)}.$$
Now, let $2x+1=3p^2,$ where $p\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$3p^2+6p+7\geq8\sqrt{3p^2+1}$$ or
$$(p-1)^2(3p^2+18p-5)\geq0,$$ which is true for $p\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt3}.$

Comment: It is nice to reduce to $\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-3x\right)$. (+1)

Answer (score 1):

**Supplement to Michael Rozenberg's nice answer**.

*Remarks*: I provide an alternative proof (using AM-GM and C-S) for
$\sqrt{3}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{x^2+1}-3x\right)$
if $x, y, z > 0$ and $xy + yz + zx = 1$. Please see details in [Michael Rozenberg's result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699113/is-it-true-that-p2-2-sqrt3r-cdot-p-geq-20rr-5r2-for-an-acute-triang/4699198#4699198).

According Michael Rozenberg's result, it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $xy + yz + zx = 1$,
$$\sqrt{3} \ge 2\sqrt{x^2 + 1} + 2\sqrt{y^2 + 1} + 2\sqrt{z^2 + 1} - 3x - 3y - 3z. \tag{1}$$

For convenience, let $u = x\sqrt 3, v = y\sqrt 3, w = z\sqrt 3$. It suffices to prove that,
for all $u, v, w \ge 0$ with $uv + vw + wu = 3$,
$$3 \ge 2\sqrt{u^2+3} + 2\sqrt{v^2 + 3}
+ 2\sqrt{w^2 + 3} - 3u - 3v - 3w. \tag{2}$$

By AM-GM, we have
$$2\sqrt{u^2 + 3} \le \frac{2(u^2 + 3)}{u + 3}
+ \frac{u + 3}{2} = \frac52 u + \frac72 - \frac{8u}{u + 3}.\tag{3}$$

Using (2) and (3), it suffices to prove that, for all $u, v, w \ge 0$ with $uv + vw + wu = 3$,
$$3 \ge \sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \left(\frac52 u + \frac72 - \frac{8u}{u + 3}\right) - 3u - 3v - 3w$$
or
$$\frac{u+v+w}{2} + \frac{8u}{u + 3} + \frac{8v}{v + 3}
+ \frac{8w}{w + 3} - \frac{15}{2} \ge 0. \tag{4}$$

By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, we have
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{8u}{u + 3}
\ge \frac{(4u + 4v + 4w)^2}{\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} 2u(u+3)} = \frac{16(u+v+w)^2}{
2(u+v+w)^2 + 6(u+v+w) - 12} \tag{5}$$
where we use $uv + vw + wu = 3$ to simplify the denominator.

Using (4) and (5), it suffices to prove that,
for all $u, v, w \ge 0$ with $uv + vw + wu = 3$,
$$\frac{u+v+w}{2} +  \frac{16(u+v+w)^2}{
 2(u+v+w)^2 + 6(u+v+w) - 12}  - \frac{15}{2} \ge 0$$
or
$$\frac{(Q + 10)(Q - 3)^2}{2Q^2 + 6Q - 12} \ge 0$$
which is true, where $Q = u + v + w$.

We are done.

Comment: Which step did you use the fact of the triangle being acute?

Comment: @youthdoo You can see Michael Rozenberg's result: Now, let $a^2+b^2-c^2=z,$ $a^2+c^2-b^2=y$ and $b^2+c^2-a^2=x$.

Thus, $x>0$, $y>0$, $z>0$, $a=\sqrt{\frac{y+z}{2}},$ $b=\sqrt{\frac{x+z}{2}}$,$c=\sqrt{\frac{x+y}{2}}$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-3x\right)$$ or
$$\sqrt{3}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{x^2+1}-3x\right),$$ where $xy+xz+yz=1$.

Comment: @youthdoo I only provide an alternative proof (using AM-GM and C-S) of $\sqrt{3}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{x^2+1}-3x\right)$ for $x, y, z > 0$ and $xy + yz + zx = 1$. So I don't provide the content before this.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution.

In my previous post I showed that we need to prove that:$$\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(2\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}-3x\right),$$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Now, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{(x+y)(x+z)}\leq\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+y)(x+z)}{2x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}(2x+y+z)}=2\sqrt{(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+y)(x+z)}{2x+y+z}}$$ and it's enough to prove that:
$$4\sqrt{(x+y+z)\sum_{cyc}\frac{(x+y)(x+z)}{2x+y+z}}\leq3(x+y+z)+\sqrt{3(xy+xz+yz)}.$$
Now, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove a linear inequality of $w^3$, which by [uvw](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h278791) says that it's enough to prove the last inequality in the following cases.

1. $z\rightarrow0^+$ and $y=1$, which gives
   $$4\sqrt{(x+1)\left(\frac{(x+1)x}{2x+1}+\frac{x+1}{2+x}+\frac{x}{x+1}\right)}\leq3(x+1)+\sqrt{3x}$$ or
   $$4\sqrt{\frac{(x+1)^2(x^2+4x+1)}{2x^2+5x+2}+x}\leq3(x+1)+\sqrt{3x}.$$
   Let $x+1=2k\sqrt{x}.$

Thus, $k\geq1$ and we need to prove here $$4\sqrt{\frac{4k^2(4k^2+2)}{8k^2+1}+1}\leq6k+\sqrt3$$ or
$$34k^4+96\sqrt3k^3-196k^2+12\sqrt3k-13\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$(34k^4+96\sqrt3k^3-196k^2+12\sqrt3k-13)'=$$
$$=136k^3+288\sqrt3k^2-392k+12\sqrt3>$$
$$>136k+288k-392k>0$$ and
$$34k^4+96\sqrt3k^3-196k^2+12\sqrt3k-13\geq$$
$$\geq34+96\sqrt3-196+12\sqrt3-13=108\sqrt3-175>0.$$
2. $y=z=1$.

We need to prove that:
$$4\sqrt{(x+2)\left(\frac{x+1}{2}+\frac{4(x+1)}{x+3}\right)}\leq3(x+2)+\sqrt{3(2x+1)},$$ which after squaring gives
$$6(x+2)(x+3)\sqrt{3(2x+1)}\geq59+115x+43x^2-x^3,$$ which is obvious for $59+115x+43x^2-x^3<0$.

But for $59+115x+43x^2-x^3\geq0$ we need to prove that
$$108(x+2)^2(x+3)^2(2x+1)\geq(59+115x+43x^2-x^3)^2$$ or $$(x-1)^2(407+1500x+1250x^2+300x^3-x^4)\geq0,$$ which is true because
$$407+1500x+1250x^2+300x^3-x^4\geq$$
$$\geq407+1500x+1250x^2+300x^3-x(59+115x+43x^2)>0$$ and we are done.